# Delete a record from web table scenario in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am writing an automation script and one of the scenarios I wish to automate is to delete a record from grid, now what I am doing is finding the xpath of the list of delete buttons in the grid, and I'm hitting an 'if' condition where I state that if the delete button is displayed on page delete the first record or else driver.close(); but I guess Selenium isn't checking the condition, it is directly showing me NoSuchElement exception. Can someone please suggest me a better way or some other alternative to automate such a scenario. The code I'm using:=

```
    //resourceSchedulePage - Class object
    //clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn() - method that returns the WebElement
    schedulerPage.clickResourceSchedule().click();
    logger.info("Resource schedule link is clicked");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    if(resourceSchedulePage.clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn().isDisplayed())
    {
        resourceSchedulePage.clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn().click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    else
    {
        driver.close();
    }
```

**Implementation :**

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"gridResourceSchedule\"]//td[6]/a[2]") 
WebElement deleteResourceScheduleBtn; 

public WebElement clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn() throws InterruptedException { 
      synchronized (driver) { 
          driver.wait(1000); } 
     return deleteResourceScheduleBtn; }
```

Comment: This is a web element `clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn`, show us how you have implemented this.

Comment: @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"gridResourceSchedule\"]//td[6]/a[2]")

WebElement deleteResourceScheduleBtn;



public WebElement clickDeleteResourceScheduleDataBtn() throws InterruptedException
 {
  return deleteResourceScheduleBtn;
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @pburgr, here is the implementation for `findElements`

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("Delete button xpath")).size() > 0 ) {
    System.out.println("Delete button is avilable");
    // you can click on delete here, or whatever you wanna do. 
}
else {
    System.out.println("Delete button isn't avilable");
    driver.close();
}
```

also there is a way to handle this situation which is `try catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

`element.isDisplayed()` can be used for existing element only. It returns `false` only if the element is found but is not displayed (hidden=true f.e.).
To check if element exists you can use `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(...);` In case no element is found, you'll get empty List instead of `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: So again my scenario is I wish to delete a record from the grid if a record is indeed present in the grid, if no record is present in the grid I want the browser to get closed that's when the else condition comes in the picture, so can you suggest me a way to write a script to run this scenario

Comment: @ChinmayBhagat :  You need to read again what he has written.